# Convolutional Conditional Variational Autoencoder Implementation

Tags: conv-neural-network, autoencoders, variational-bayes

This may be a rather trivial question, but I am somewhat confused. I have been able to implement a convolutional variational autoencoder. I have also been able to implement a conditional variational autoencoder, though with fully connected layers only. Now, I wish to combine them, as I want to try generating images with specific attributes rather than just on a single messy latent space.

From the guides I read, the way I implemented the conditional variational autoencoder was by concatenating the original input image with an encoding of the label/attribute data when building the encoder, and doing the same to the latent space variation when building the decoder/generator. This has worked quite simply, as the layers are all fully connected.

How would I add convolutional layers into this though? For the decoder it makes sense, but for the encoder, I don't think it would make sense to concatenate the attribute data to the image then do convolutions on that. Should I do several convolutions on the input image, flatten the resulting data, then concatenate the labels, or what?

The closest description I've found is slide 70 of [this presentation](http://slazebni.cs.illinois.edu/spring17/lec12_vae.pdf), but it doesn't quite make it clear enough for me.

Comment: I am trying to implement similar thing too. Accroding to some approches from gan, I think its possible to use cnn for image, and then concat with label, end up with a fully connected layer. I will atach my github repository here after completion.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/attribute2image/
I believe this paper can help you understand this problem

Comment: @JkRong Thanks for the help, I have successfully replicated large parts of the model described in the paper using Keras.